# Why is this relation $R=\{ (a,b), (b,c), (a,c) \}$ transitive?

Tags: relations

I am confused here. For the set $\{ a, b, c\}$ how is the relation $\{(a, b), (b, c), (a, c)\}$ transitive ?

Comment: **Hint:** Write out the definition of transitive.

Answer (score 2):

You only have two pairs of the form $\;(a,b),\,\,(b,c)\in R\;$ , and **also** $\;(a,c)\in R\;$ , so it is true that whenever $\;(x,y),\,(y,z)\in R\;$ , also $\;(x,z)\in R\;$, and that's transitivity

Comment: Wont we look for transitivity for (b,c) and (a,c) , like for (b,c) there is no (c,a ) or (c,b) ?

Comment: @abhay Exactly. In those cases, by definition, transitivity doesn't apply. *only* in the cases when it applies we can check, and in this case it happens in the **only** case we can apply it.

Answer (score 1):

Because no matter how you select elements $x,y,z \in \{a, b, c\}$ such that $xRy$ and $yRz$ (hint: there's only **one** way), you have $xRz$, which is what it means to be transitive.

Comment: So what about the relation { (a,b) } on the set { a,b,c} ? Is that transitive ?

Comment: @abhay Yes, it is.

Comment: @joanpemo. How ?

Comment: Look at the definition of transitivity, and realise that there's no way to select elements that satisfy the requirements, that means there's no elements that have to satisfy anything for transitivity to be true. - It's just like the empty relation, that's transitive too, neither case is particularly interesting though.

Comment: Please make it simpler for me :p